# Azure Serverless Function @TableInput binding advantages over calling API within Functions with static fields

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure Functions, after exploring Azure Serverless Functions, where I can bind CosmosDB with @TableInput/@TableOutput I am able to successfully do CRUD operations in existing COSMOS DB.
I can also connect COSMOS DB using table space api using static fields which seems will reduce the connection request when scaled up.
However I would like to understand how it internally @TableInput/@TableOutput works, for example is there any existing connection pools from where this binding uses or for every fresh request a new connection request is established.This I need to understand to know if there are there any performance benifits using Bindings over static final fields.

Comment: the code of the cosmos db binding can b found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB

Comment: Thanks , issues is resolved.